# jquery .load() google docs form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, load

i have a form created via google docs like https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dFgwMWhsallRZ2ViMWNaSVF1VmF2d0E6MQ.

is it possible to load this page into a div with jquery:

var content='https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dFgwMWhsallRZ2ViMWNaSVF1VmF2d0E6MQ';

$('#some_elem').load(content);

update: #some_elem is a dynamically created element.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Which basically means you cannot load content from `site1.com` on `site2.com` via ajax for security reasons, this behaviour is built into modern browsers so there is no easy way around it unless you control both requesting and requested content. Your best bet is to use an iframe to get around this.

Comment: thanks. i think of processing the remote file (ie the google form) first with a local php script triggered by ajax call, then display the response form this php script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Google Doc's form creation, what scripts it's possible to use there, etc but it should work, as long as they are on the same domain. But why don't you just try it?